# Embed map in a website

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I am using arcgis server 10.0. I published a mxd file using arcgis manager resources.
I see the web url `http://cosmic-dellt410:8399/arcgis/services/DD/MapServer` but it says get method not allowed. I noted that the wsdl get generated but not the rest api.  Any idea why?  How do I embed the map on my website?

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS forum. Looks like you are using ArcGIS Server 10 Java edition. You need to use REST service to link your map to your web site or create custom web application and then integrate it to your site. Please explain your question with detail.

Comment: +1 Actually it depends development scenario i.e. you can simply use REST service in Java Script API and then integrate that html/jsp file with your website etc. so please explain your question in detail. May be useful for you http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_java_help/index.html#//00920000008p000000

Comment: Is your rest config pointing to the correct location? A lot depends on your network configuration. Do you have a reverse proxy? Can your server route to its own external address?